# Minishift console on Azure VM is not accessible from remote browser

Tags: azure, minishift

Minishift console is not displaying in browser

I have installed minishift on Azure VM. To access minishift console from browser, I have done port forwarding with following commands.

firewall-cmd --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-forward-port=port=8443:proto=tcp:toport=8443:toaddr=192.168.42.90
firewall-cmd --reload

Azure VM machine address is :- 23.99.65.77
minishift VM address :- 192.168.42.90

If i am accessing it through curl command, I am getting response html page
curl -k https://23.99.65.77:8443/console/catalog
If I am accessing it from browser(Chrome), I am not getting minishift console and following error are coming

> https://192.168.42.90:8443/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-web-console&response_type=code&state=eyJ0aGVuIjoiLyIsIm5vbmNlIjoiMTU2MDMzODcyMjUxNS0xODU5OTIzNjQyNDQ3OTczNjQ0MTExNzU0MDM4MDI2NzUxMjkyNDgxMTcxNzc2MTMxMzc5NDAwMzEwNDYwMTE2OTM1OTM5NzE5MTY5In0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.42.90%3A8443%2Fconsole%2Foauth
>   is unreachable. ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

It seems some certificate issue with browser.

Comment: why do you think this is certificate related? unreachable means you didnt expose the vm port, most likely. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413031/can-not-access-azure-vm-thru-port-8888

Answer (score 0):

I exposed port 8443 from Azure portal. See below screen shot/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBt8m.png)

Comment: Any leads on  above issue. Appreciated your help